# Bind react component to part of redux state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have redux store that looks something like this:

```
{
  user: {},
  alerts: [],
  reports: [],
  sourses: []
}
```

For each one of this parts of state i have a bunch of React Components wrapped in a container wich connected via `react-redux`. And has `mapStateToProps` like this

```
(state) => {alerts: state.alerts}
(state, ownProps) => {alert: _.filter(state, {id: ownProps.curId})}
```

Problem that when i for example launch some action for Alerts like `CREATE_ALERT` or `EDIT_ALERT` and redux state updated, **ALL REACT COMPONENTS WILL RESPOND TO THIS CHANGE** even ones that works with different parts like `sources` or `reports`.

My question: how to "bind" certain components to certain parts of a tree. So each container component **WILL UPDATE ONLY WHEN APROPRIATE PART OF REDUX STATE UPDATED** and ignore other changes.

Expected behavior

Dispatch `CREATE_ALERT` -> Alert reducer -> Redux store update -> **ONLY** Alert container component re-rendering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are changing state in redux the whole state becomes just a new object.
Then your component is given by this new object (new reference) and re-renderes itself.

To fix this behaviour you need to add some logic to compare if your component got props with different value (not reference).

The easiest and fastest way is to use [React.PureComponent](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-api.html#react.purecomponent). You can also override `shouldComponentUpdate` function and handle changes by yourself. But note that `PureComponent` works only with primitives (it does a shallow compare).

Check also [Immutable.js](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/) which helps you with intelligent way of changing references of props.

Comment: Thanks i'll check it out. Btw what do you think about this?
https://www.npmjs.com/package/reselect
Did you have some expirience with this?

Comment: Reselect is nice momoizing library for redux selectors. Its momoizing properties will fix your problem. However I strongly recommend using `PureComponent` for a start (it's already in React).

Comment: I'll try first/ I'll put some tests this evening. With PureComponents, Selectors and ImmutableJS
And report results here

Comment: Note that `PureComponent`s use shallow compare so it can work improperly if you pass objects as props.

Answer (score 0):

if you use connect method, then pass only selected redux state to the component, this will prevent rendering of other components

example:

**User Component:**

```
 const mapStateToProps = state =>({
  users: state.users
  });

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(User)
```

Alert Component:

```
const mapStateToProps = state =>({
  alerts: state.alerts
  });

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Alert)
```

Comment: If the first part of the accepted answer is true "When you are changing state in redux the whole state becomes just a new object. Then your component is given by this new object (new reference) and re-renderes itself.", then wouldn't the component still re-render regardless because it still gets a new copy of the state, even if it's the same thing as before?

Comment: @AdamPrax redux is one big object made up of multiple small object, so when a changes happens only sub-objects are changed not the actual redux object. so if you make change to User object of redux , other state objects will remain unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out: [Avoid Reconciliation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/optimizing-performance.html#avoid-reconciliation)

There explains what **Neciu** says.

Answer (score 0):

Container components created with `connect` will always receive notifications of all updates to the store.

The responsibility for consuming these updates falls on the receiving `connect` component. It  should contain the logic to extract the data relevant to it.